# Would a question about airport history be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask about the history of the "Superbay" at KSFO. I could also imagine questions such as how an airport got its name/code (like KORD), or about the unusual layout of [EDDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Tempelhof_Airport).

Would questions like these also be on-topic? If so, are there some requirements for them being a good fit for this site?

Comment: If [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11318/62) is on topic - and I think it is - then the questions you mentioned certainly are too

Comment: @Pondlife that seems less historical and more related to procedures.

Comment: It's debatable, e.g. I could argue that airport naming is also a procedural issue because there are standards etc. involved. But most questions will have multiple tags anyway, so we can easily handle multiple perspectives on one question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I would say yes. We already have an [aviation-history](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-history) tag and the topics you listed I think would nicely fit in it.